# details and reference (for undergraduate student) on the constructions and topology of $\mathbb{RP}^n$

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, projective-space

I want to know if there is a "natural" topology on $\mathbb{RP}^n$, if yes, how it is defined?

(a natural topology for me is a topology which, unless said differently, it is considered without said explicitly, for example, $\mathbb{R}^n$ and the euclidean topology, or the product topology on a product space)

To be more specific, suppose i have to calculate the homology groups (or fundamental group) for $\mathbb{RP}^n$. Clearly I have to choose two open sets with certain conditions.

My problem is I can't figure out what is open and what is not. (i'm interested in "viewing" the open sets on the quotient of $S^n$ and the other representations)

Another doubt is the construction of $\mathbb{RP}^n$. The quotient and CW-complex constructions are pretty clear, the one starting with an affine space not.

I tried to search around, and the wiki seems to have some answers, but i need some titles of books (undergraduate level) to understand better the topic.

Hope there is no similar question already asked.

Comment: One may consider $\mathbf{RP}^n$ as the quotient of the $n$-sphere by the relation identifying antipodal points, and with the quotient topology so induced.

Comment: There is a theorem stating that on a real finite dimensional vector space there is a unique Hausdorff topology which makes it a [topological vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space). The quotient topology on $\Bbb{RP}^n$ would then be quite "natural". I'm currently unable to find a proper reference, though.

Comment: @A.P. mmh, some kind of topology derived from the euclidean on the sphere? (i think this is pretty natural, but maybe are the same of yours)

Comment: It looks like Bourbaki proves a related result in page 2 of the first chapter of the book [Topological Vector Spaces](http://books.google.it/books?id=kB7vAAAAMAAJ). Namely, that a vector space $E$ of finite dimension over a topological division ring $К$ can be endowed with a *canonical* topology. As for your question, there is an isomorphism between the Euclidean space $\Bbb E^n$ and $\Bbb R^n$, so you can consider the subspace topology on $S^{n-1}$ induced by the canonical topology.

Comment: @A.P. yes, i think it is the most natural choice to do. Can anyone solve my other doubts or give me some references (the one in the answer it's too specific I think) ?

Comment: Note that $\Bbb{RP}^n$ is covered by "standard" open sets $U_i=\{(x_0:\dotsc:x_n)\mid x_i\neq0\}$, which are homeomorphic to the affine space $\Bbb R^n$. You can define $\Bbb{RP}^n$ by "glueing" together $n+1$ affine spaces $\Bbb R^n$, so that they correspond to the $U_i$. I think, though, that this construction is best understood in the context of algebraic geometry (where it is easily generalised).

Comment: @RicPed Can you explain what exactly your question is?  If you need a reference for the construction of $\mathbf{RP}^n$ as a quotient of the $n$-sphere, you can take a look at literally any introductory textbook on topology.

Comment: @Adeel i need a Reference For a book or an article or something that explain the topological properties of the projective Space. But as I said, My doubt are about the costruction using an affine space, and which topology i give to it (naturally) with this kind of definition.

Comment: What do you mean by "construction using **an** affine space"? The only two constructions I can think of using affine spaces are the one I hinted at in my previous comment (using $n+1$ spaces), and the one which looks at $\Bbb{RP}^n$ as the space of hyperplanes of $\Bbb{A}^n_{\Bbb R}$, which is virtually the same as the vector space quotient construction.

Comment: I think it is the second, because i've always read of affine space with lines or spaces at infinity. What i need is a clarification about this kind of costruction

Comment: Then you could have a look at pages [368-369](http://books.google.it/books?id=yCsDO425PC0C&lpg=PR1&hl=it&pg=PA368#v=onepage&q&f=false) of the book *Ideals, Varieties, and Algorithms* by Cox, Little, and O'Shea. I think that point of view is explained quite clearly there.

Answer (score 3):

Chapter 5 of [Topology and Groupoids](http://pages.bangor.ac.uk/~mas010/topgpds.html) is on "Projective and other spaces" and deals simultaneously with the real, complex, and quaternionic projective spaces, and their cell structures. The details of the latter are on p. 150.

The calculation of fundamental groups is easy, since they are trivial except in the real case, when you get $\mathbb Z_2$ since there is a double covering map  $S^n \to \mathbf{RP}^n, n >1$. You can also get this from the cell structure which for the real case starts off $e^0 \cup e^1 \cup e^2\cup \cdots $ where the attaching map of the $2$-cell is of degree $2$. For the homology of these spaces the  results on cellular homology are  needed, which I won't do here.

Comment: thank you, but i need a "more general view" on the projective space than only cell structure. Anyway, i'll look a preview on google books if there is one.

Comment: @Ric: The cell structure in this exposition is just one of the properties deduced from the general view of projective spaces over the reals, complex numbers and quaternions. You could compare T&G with Porteous "Topological Geometry".